# Will I be able to play as the Wraith on the PC?

Tags: evolve

I was watching some video on Youtube and it was mentioned that BETA testers get access to the Wraith on Evolve for Xbox One. I plan on getting Evolve for my computer. Will I still be able to play as the Wraith if I unlock it? I plan on getting it for PC so I can play multiplayer with my friends without the internet fee like on the Xbox and PS4.

Comment: (In case you were thinking about it, be aware that the PC version will not let you multiplayer with any friends who bought the Xbox or PS versions.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Wraith is available to play on the PC. There is no platform exclusive content. Here's a screenshot from the PC version of the game, which clearly shows that Wraith is available on PC:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more information to this to back it up? It does answer the question, but something to confirm that it is true is needed.

Comment: @ShadowZ. The confirmation is that I own the game on PC. I'll take a screenshot when I get home, but honestly, this is just common knowledge, really. The asker questions comes from a point of confusion.

Comment: I have yet to play it, so I had no prior knowledge to anything going on with it. I just saw that the info should have been backed up, and asked about it.

Comment: @ShadowZ. : Yes, there's nothing wrong with asking. I was being a bit grumpy about it, not sure why. My apologies.

Comment: Its okay, we all have those types of days.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up as I was highly confused on the issue. I did play the BETA over at a friend's house and logged in many hours as the wraith on playstation and had a lot of fun playing as her and I got really great as the wraith. So good as a matter of fact that if you see birds, odds are it is a trap.